# Is there any way to dynamically define types in typeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, material-ui

I'm trying to create an SX styling file where I have the style object of type SXPropsTypes.
I want to access the style properties in another file, but the autocomplete doesn't bring the suggestions for the keys of my style object

style.ts

```
import { SxPropType } from '@app/theme/types';

const style: SxPropType = {
  text: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontWeight: 700,
    fontSize: 20,
    letterSpacing: '1.2px',
    marginBottom: 7,
  },
};

export default style;
```

when I define a typeStyle for style in the default export, the auto complete works and brings me the key suggestions.

```
import { SxPropType } from '@app/theme/types';


type typeStyle = {
  text: SxPropType;
};

const style: SxPropType = {
  text: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontWeight: 700,
    fontSize: 20,
    letterSpacing: '1.2px',
    marginBottom: 7,
  },
};

export default style as typeStyle;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTg9W.png)

I want to make this typing more automatic, so when I create a key in the style object it already gives me the suggestion automatically in the auto complete, but without always having to define a new field in the typeStyle

I tried to dynamically type the typeStyle object, but I was not successful, I want to type the typeStyle object (dynamically/automatically) according to the keys of the style object

Answer (score 0):

You can define a type lets say `StyleKeys` which extracts the keys from your style object using the `keyof` operator, and then use a mapped type to create the `typeStyle` type with those keys. something like this:

```js
// ...
type StyleKeys = keyof SxPropType;

type typeStyle = {
  [key in StyleKeys]: SxPropType;
};

const style: SxPropType = {
  text: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontWeight: 700,
    fontSize: 20,
    letterSpacing: '1.2px',
    marginBottom: 7,
  },
};

const typedStyle = style as typeStyle;
```